# How to perform polynomial landmark detection with deep learning

Tags: deep-learning, conv-neural-network, recurrent-neural-network, image-segmentation

I am trying to build a system to segment vehicles using a deep convolutional neural network. I am familiar with predicting a set amount of points (i.e. ending a neural architecture with a Dense layer with 4 neurons to predict 2 points(x,y) coords for both). However, vehicles come in many different shapes and sizes and one vehicle may require more segmentation points than another. How can I create a neural network that can have different amounts of output values? I imagine I could use a RNN of some sort but would like a little guidance. Thank you

For example, in the following image the two vehicles have a different number of labeled keypoints.

[image]

Comment: Do you have any examples that can clarify what you need?

Comment: @Nightmerker, please see image example I added. Thanks

Comment: So these points will trace the silhouette of the car, right?

Comment: Right...just trying to perform an image segmentation task

Comment: This is a good question, but you may get better or more helpful answers at https://stats.stackexchange.com/ or https://datascience.stackexchange.com/

Comment: thanks @Wil...i will share over there instead

Comment: how many annotated examples do you have? who did the annotations? how difficult is is to compute a binary segmentation mask given the points?

Comment: posted [here](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/q/51127/37752)